# Fixed vertical menu bar

Tags: html, css, menu, fixed, nav

So I have a vertical navigation bar. I want to make it so it will stay fixed on the left side as long as you scroll down but there is a problem. If I add a text next to it, a white space will appear.

Here's the preview:
www.dp-gaming.url.ph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is the **default margin** from the `<h1>`

Set this in your css:

```
h1 {margin:0;}
```

If you want to set all default margins from all elements, you could use this code:

```
* {margin:0;}
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help. As a new user i ask you, could you accept the answer?

Comment: In 5 minutes I will be able to.

Answer (score 0):

just make it's position property fixed,

```
.class{
    position : fixed;
 }
```